# Checkbox to change state of label, tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I've recently started using tkinter, trying to create a very basic GUI for a til system. The idea is to have 8 checkboxes, that represent 8 different items, and when the checkbox is ticked or unticked, the label that shows the total price of the order changes accordingly.

The code here shows what I currently have relating to the checkboxes and the price. I want the LabelP ( price label ) to show the price of what has been selected on the menu at any given time. My current attempt at it doesn't seem to work. I'm relatively new to tkinter in general, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this. I'm using a dictionary to store each item's checkbox, price, name and variable (holds the checked/not checked value).
When ever a check box is selected, the recalculate method.
The recalculate method looks to see which items are selected and adds their price to the total displayed on the screen.
This way you don't have to 'hardcode' each item, you just add a new item to the list of `stock_items` and it will be displayed on screen when you run the code.
A bit more advanced than your example but will do what you want.

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except:
    import Tkinter as tk

import time

#Create an array containing our stock items
#Each item is a dictionary with price and name fields
stock_items = []
stock_items.append({'price':2.0,'name':'Item 1'})
stock_items.append({'price':1.5,'name':'Item 2'})
stock_items.append({'price':5,'name':'Item 3'})
stock_items.append({'price':7,'name':'Item 4'})

class Till(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None,**kw):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master=master,**kw)
        self.price_string=tk.StringVar()
        tk.Label(self,text="Price: ").grid(row=0,column=0)
        tk.Label(self,textvariable=self.price_string).grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.items = []
        #For each stock item, create an IntVar, a checkbox and keep record of the price/name
        for idx,item in enumerate(stock_items):
            new_item = {}
            new_item['var'] = tk.IntVar()
            new_item['check'] = tk.Checkbutton(self,
                                                  text=item['name'],
                                                  variable=new_item['var'],
                                                  command=self.recalculate)
            new_item['check'].grid(row=idx+1)
            new_item['name'] = item['name']
            new_item['price'] = item['price']
            self.items.append(new_item)


    #Recalculate is called when ever a checkbox is checked/unchecked
    def recalculate(self):
        total_price = 0
        #Go through each item and if it is selected add its price to the total
        for item in self.items:
            if item['var'].get():
                total_price += item['price']
        #Display out total price
        self.price_string.set('£/$ {:.2f}'.format(total_price))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    Till(root).grid()
    root.mainloop()
```